# Subset all rows for a group which has specific character in another column

Tags: r

I want to subset all rows for IDs in a data set which have "P" in variable B.

My data:

```
Data <- cbind(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), B=c("A1", "P2", "B2", "P1", "B1", "B1", "A4", "D1")) 

   ID  B   
 "1" "A1"
 "1" "P2"
 "2" "B2"
 "2" "P1"
 "2" "B1"
 "2" "B1"
 "3" "A4"
 "3" "D1"
```

My desired output would be:

```
   ID  B   
 "1" "A1"
 "1" "P2"
 "2" "B2"
 "2" "P1"
 "2" "B1"
 "2" "B1"
```

I tried fiddling with grep and looked at %like% but could not figure out how to retain all rows within groups if P occurs for that ID in variable B.

```
Ps <- Data %>% group_by(Data$ID) %>% grep("P", Data$B )
```

produces an error because of character in variable B

Feels like I have seen a solution to this before but I have not been able to find it. Any ideas or directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
Data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), B=c("A1", "P2", "B2", "P1", "B1", "B1", "A4", "D1"))
> Data %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(any(grepl("P",B)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID      B
  <dbl> <fctr>
1     1     A1
2     1     P2
3     2     B2
4     2     P1
5     2     B1
6     2     B1
```

Note the use of `data.frame()` rather than `cbind`. If you want to create data frames, try to avoid `cbind`.

Also, most **dplyr** verbs don't require you to reference variables with `$` like you did as in `group_by(Data$ID)`. Just the column name is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the advice regarding data.frame and $!

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option with `grep` and `table` would be

```
Data[Data[,"ID"] %in% names(which(table(Data[,"ID"], grepl("P",Data[, "B"]))[,2]!=0)),]
```